# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /header.jsp at line 104

Tags: java, jsp, connection

I get the following error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
>   JSP page /header.jsp at line 104

```
 <%if (categoryDAO.getListCategory() != null) {
      for (Category ds : categoryDAO.getListCategory()) {%>
<li><a href="products.jsp?category=<%=ds.getCategoryID()%>"> <%=ds.getCategoryName()%></a></li>
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jsp.header_jsp._jspService(header_jsp.java:235)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

There is my categoryDAO

```
  public ArrayList<Category> getListCategory() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Connection cons = DBconnect.getConnecttion();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
    ArrayList<Category> list = new ArrayList<>();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;//cai
    try {
        try {
            ps = (PreparedStatement) cons.prepareStatement(sql);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            return null;
        }
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Category category = new Category();
            category.setCategoryID(rs.getLong("category_id"));
            category.setCategoryName(rs.getString("category_name"));
            list.add(category);
        }
        cons.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
         cons.close();
        return null;

    }
    return list;
}
```

Here is my connect to database

```
 static final String DBNAME = "shop";
static final String USERNAME = "root";
static final String PASSWORD = "vancao";
private static ResultSet rs = null;
private static Connection connection = null;

public static Connection getConnecttion() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    if (connection != null) {
        return connection;
    } else {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + HOSTNAME + ":3306/" + DBNAME + "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, USERNAME,
                PASSWORD);
        return connection;
    }
}
```

i checked getListCategory() in CategoryDAO and it still work.
what happen with my code? please help me. Thanks you all.

Comment: root cause suggests the error is at line `235` not `104`, post the jsp

Comment: Do not pick and choose bits of the stack trace to show --- show the ENTIRE stack trace, COMPLETE, with all CausedBy sections, in one code block.  Also, to not modify the stack trace in any way.  Copy/Paste it from the log into the question.

Comment: Sorry Jim, that is first time i post questions. Line 235 in below, Ramanlfc

Answer (score 0):

```
if (categoryDAO.getListCategory() != null) {
          for (Category ds : categoryDAO.getListCategory()) {
  out.write("\n");
  out.write("<li><a href=\"products.jsp?category=");
  out.print(ds.getCategoryID());
  out.write(" \"> ");
  out.print(ds.getCategoryName());
  out.write("</a></li>\n");
  out.write("\n");
  out.write("                                    ");
```

line 235 is: for (Category ds : categoryDAO.getListCategory()) 
Something wrong? Ramanlfc.